# Multiple Argument pass as index value of the Array iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing QRCode application, I am getting some problem to enable barcoding symbologies. 
I have one array in which I get all barcoding symbologies from websrvice data response, need to be as enable. 
I apply static code as follow and its working for me. 
But I want to make it dynamic. Following is my code :

Please help me to make it, dynamic. I tried many approaches but not getting proper solution.

Created two array :

```
  NSMutableArray *enableSymbologies = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];  // Data from webservice response   
  NSMutableArray *symbologiesToSet = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];  // for enabling barcode symbology 

 for (int i =0 ; i < [enableSymbologies count] ; i ++)
        {
            if([[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Code39"])
            {
                [symbologiesToSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MWB_CODE_MASK_39]];
            }
            else if ([[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Code93"])
            {
                [symbologiesToSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MWB_CODE_MASK_93]];
            }
            else if ([[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Code25I"])
            {
                [symbologiesToSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MWB_CODE_MASK_25]];
            }
            else if ([[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Code25S"])
            {
                [symbologiesToSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MWB_CODE_MASK_25]];
            }
            else if ([[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Code128"])
            {
                [symbologiesToSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MWB_CODE_MASK_128]];
            }
            else if ([[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"QR"])
            {
                [symbologiesToSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MWB_CODE_MASK_QR]];
            }
            else if ([[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"EAN+UPC"])
            {
                [symbologiesToSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MWB_CODE_MASK_EANUPC]];
            }
            else if ([[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"PDF"])
            {
                [symbologiesToSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MWB_CODE_MASK_PDF]];
            }
            else if ([[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"CodaBar"])
            {
                [symbologiesToSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MWB_CODE_MASK_CODABAR]];
            }

            else
            {
                [symbologiesToSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MWB_CODE_MASK_QR]];
            }


    }
```

**// My static approach, I want to make it dynamic**

```
for (int i = 0; i < [symbologiesToSet count]; i++)
    {
        if([symbologiesToSet count] == 1)
        {
            MWB_setActiveCodes([[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:0] integerValue]);
        }
        else if([symbologiesToSet count] == 2)
        {
            MWB_setActiveCodes([[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:1] integerValue]);

        }
        else if([symbologiesToSet count] == 3)
        {
            MWB_setActiveCodes([[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:1] integerValue]  | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:2] integerValue]);

        }
        else if([symbologiesToSet count] == 4)
        {
            MWB_setActiveCodes([[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:1] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:2] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:3] integerValue]);

        }
        else if([symbologiesToSet count] == 5)
        {
            MWB_setActiveCodes([[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:1] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:2] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:3] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:4] integerValue]);

        }
        else if([symbologiesToSet count] == 6)
        {
            MWB_setActiveCodes([[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:1] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:2] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:3] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:4] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:5] integerValue]);

        }
        else if([symbologiesToSet count] == 7)
        {
            MWB_setActiveCodes([[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:1] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:2] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:3] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:4] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:5] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:6] integerValue]);

        }
        else if([symbologiesToSet count] == 8)
        {
            MWB_setActiveCodes([[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:1] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:2] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:3] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:4] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:5] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:6] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:7] integerValue]);

        }
        else if([symbologiesToSet count] == 9)
        {
            MWB_setActiveCodes([[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:1] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:2] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:3] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:4] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:5] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:6] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:7] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:8] integerValue]);
        }
    }

    #define MWB_CODE_MASK_NONE                  0x00000000u
    #define MWB_CODE_MASK_QR                    0x00000001u
    #define MWB_CODE_MASK_DM                    0x00000002u
    #define MWB_CODE_MASK_RSS                   0x00000004u
    #define MWB_CODE_MASK_39                    0x00000008u
    #define MWB_CODE_MASK_EANUPC                0x00000010u
    #define MWB_CODE_MASK_128                   0x00000020u
    #define MWB_CODE_MASK_PDF                   0x00000040u
    #define MWB_CODE_MASK_AZTEC                 0x00000080u
    #define MWB_CODE_MASK_25                    0x00000100u
    #define MWB_CODE_MASK_93                    0x00000200u
    #define MWB_CODE_MASK_CODABAR               0x00000400u
    #define MWB_CODE_MASK_ALL                   0x00ffffffu
```

Comment: what actually happens here  MWB_setActiveCodes([[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:1] integerValue]  | [[symbologiesToSet objectAtIndex:2] integerValue]);

Comment: Why do you call `MWB_setActiveCodes` `symbologiesToSet.count` times with the same argument ?

Comment: Because I want to those number of setActiveCode coming from symbologiesToSet.count.

Comment: @Desdenova : I am already use another library that is MobiScan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Here it is ..

```
if(curEvent.enablescanning == 1)
        {
            if([enableSymbologies count] == 0)
            {
                MWB_setActiveCodes(MWB_CODE_MASK_QR);
            }
            else
            {
                int globalSelectedTypes = 0;
                for (int i =0 ; i < [enableSymbologies count] ; i++)
                {
                    if([[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Code39"])
                    {
                        globalSelectedTypes = globalSelectedTypes + MWB_CODE_MASK_39;
                    }
                    else if ([[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Code93"])
                    {
                        globalSelectedTypes = globalSelectedTypes + MWB_CODE_MASK_93;
                    }
                    else if ([[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Code25I"] || [[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Code25S"])
                    {
                        globalSelectedTypes = globalSelectedTypes + MWB_CODE_MASK_25;
                    }
                    else if ([[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Code128"])
                    {
                        globalSelectedTypes = globalSelectedTypes + MWB_CODE_MASK_128;
                    }
                    else if ([[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"QR"])
                    {
                        globalSelectedTypes = globalSelectedTypes + MWB_CODE_MASK_QR;
                    }
                    else if ([[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"EAN+UPC"])
                    {
                        globalSelectedTypes = globalSelectedTypes + MWB_CODE_MASK_EANUPC;
                    }
                    else if ([[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"PDF"])
                    {
                        globalSelectedTypes = globalSelectedTypes + MWB_CODE_MASK_PDF;
                    }
                    else if ([[enableSymbologies objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"CodaBar"])
                    {
                        globalSelectedTypes = globalSelectedTypes + MWB_CODE_MASK_CODABAR;
                    }
                }

                MWB_setActiveCodes(globalSelectedTypes);
            }
        }
```